# How do I get the Onkey Function to copy the value of a input textfield to the other 3 textfields

Tags: javascript, html, forms

This is the Java Script I'm using. I can enter in the proceduredate and it copies to proceduredate2 but not 3 and 4--Same with Procedure

```
function copyTextAreaValue(id, ids) {
    // get source element
    var sourceElement = document.getElementById(id);
    if(sourceElement) {
        // copy to destination elements
        var destIds = ids.split(',');
        for(i=0; i<destIds.length; i++) {
            var destEle = document.getElementById(destIds[i]);
            if(destEle) {
                destEle.value = sourceElement.value;        
            } else {
                console.log('no dest element ' + destIds[i]);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

[Link to JSFiddle with full code](https://jsfiddle.net/m1q85tx7/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question id not clear to me. However, all I understood is you want to copy text from your current text input to other three text input. If that is true, then you can have your solution here. Please, checkout the snippet below.

```js
let el = document.getElementById('field_1');

function copyTextValue() {
  let elVal = el.value;
  document.getElementById("field_2").value = elVal;
  document.getElementById("field_3").value = elVal;
  document.getElementById("field_4").value = elVal;
}
copyTextValue();
el.oninput = copyTextValue;
el.onchange = copyTextValue;
```

```html
Today's Date: <input id="field_1" value=""/><br/>
Procedure Date: <input id="field_2" value=""/> <br/>
Date of Procedure:  <input id="field_3" value=""/> <br/>
Surgery Date:  <input id="field_4" value=""/> <br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function copyTextfieldValue(id, ids) {
    
        // get source element
        var sourceElement = document.getElementById(id);
    
        if(sourceElement) {
    
    
            // copy to destination elements
            var destIds = ids.split(',');
    
    
    
            for(i=0; i<destIds.length; i++) {
    
                var destEle = document.getElementById(destIds[i]);
    
                if(destEle) {
                    destEle.value = sourceElement.value;        
                } else {
                    //console.log('no dest element ' + destIds[i]);
                          
                }
                
            }
        }
    
    }
```

```html
<input id="t1">
<input id="t2">
<input id="t3">
<input id="t4">
<input type="button" value='copy' onclick="copyTextfieldValue('t1','t2,t3,t4');">
```

Your code seems to work fine. See the snippet.

Comment: How can I manipulate it to type in the first field and it automatically copies to the others without using a copy button. It works copying from the first field to the second but the other 2 textfields it doesn't copy @Hardik Shaha

Comment: <input id="t1" onkeyup="copyTextfieldValue('t1','t2,t3,t4');"> Just this.

Comment: I added that click on this link https://jsfiddle.net/m1q85tx7/ you type in the first procedure date field and it copies to the second but not the other 2

Comment: Here you go. https://jsfiddle.net/xk135ebj/. You should write the ids like 'ProcedureDate2,ProcedureDate3,ProcedureDate4'. (Without quotes and any space between them.)

Comment: thanks actually that works!! I was just writing it wrong!!